# How to get user friends permission in Graph API from Facebook after the user has logged in

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

In my app I need to ask user for user_friends permission only when the user opts a specific service. Till this time the user has already logged in and I don't want to ask for user_friends list permission at login. So how do I ask for permission when the user is already logged in ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `FB.login` again (if you are using the JS SDK, that is), with the `user_friends` scope. If it does not work directly, use `reauthenticate`:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication/

Comment: Thanks for the answer @luschn but I need to do it with graph API.

Comment: not sure how exactly you do the login, you should add that to your question. but either way, you should just be able to lead the user to the login process with the additional scope.